# Create external content type without using SharePoint Designer

Tags: external-content-type

I have a web service and I need to create an external content type. I am using SPD but that is not working. It is asking me to select at least one field and the errors will not go away. So I am stuck with it.

Is there no otherway to build an external content type?

[image]

Comment: Which data source are you connecting to??

Comment: I am using WCF service data source

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you are trying to map Int32 to a field that is not Int32 (in your case 'username' which I assume is some text\string value) you need to map to INT32 field.

Answer (score -1):

From the screenshot provided select the ID fields as your identifier field, all the errors will be gone